# How to show html string in text widget flutter

Tags: android, html, ios, flutter, cross-platform

How to show html tag string in flutter, i have tried a plugin and its not working.

```
new HtmlView(
     data: html,
     baseURL: "", // optional, type String
     onLaunchFail: (url) { // optional, type Function
     print("launch $url failed");
   }
```

This is my html

```
“Follow<a class='sup'><sup>pl</sup></a> what was sent down to you from your Lord, and do not follow other guardians apart from Him. Little do <span class='h'>you remind yourselves</span><a class='f'><sup f=2437>1</sup></a>.”
```

i user flutter_html_view: "^0.5.10"  this plugin

Comment: Can you post flutter version?

Comment: @NagendraBadiganti  Flutter (Channel beta, v1.0.0, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G65, locale en-IN)

Comment: check with  flutter_html: ^0.8.2 dependency. it works great for me all the time. I just posted an answer. If it works, give the thumb up.

Comment: This plugin simply cannot render well your html code. Read [docs](https://github.com/PonnamKarthik/FlutterHtmlView)  `This plugin does't support rendering full html code `

Comment: The webview_flutter plugin from the Flutter Team is working pretty well for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55149298

Comment: I think this plugin is gone

Answer (score 88):

This plugin doesn`t have any issue, I just created a sample with your HTML and it works fine. Try to replace with below snippet and see if that works.

```
dependencies:
  flutter_html: ^0.8.2
```

and imports and code to render html

```
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';
import 'package:html/dom.dart' as dom;


 body: new Center(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Html(
                data: """
                <div>Follow<a class='sup'><sup>pl</sup></a> 
                  Below hr
                    <b>Bold</b>
                <h1>what was sent down to you from your Lord</h1>, 
                and do not follow other guardians apart from Him. Little do 
                <span class='h'>you remind yourselves</span><a class='f'><sup f=2437>1</sup></a></div>
                """,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                onLinkTap: (url) {
                  print("Opening $url...");
                },
                customRender: (node, children) {
                  if (node is dom.Element) {
                    switch (node.localName) {
                      case "custom_tag": // using this, you can handle custom tags in your HTML 
                        return Column(children: children);
                    }
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
          )
```

[image]

Comment: do u know another plugin beside flutter_html, this plugin cannot render table and is not selectable, thankyou

Comment: flutter_html supports <table>,<tbody>,<td>,<th>,<tr> now.  Only thing it doesn't support is <style> which can be an issue for some people.

Comment: the html data converts the div tags to spans on inspection.  I need the div and the div id to be retained.

Comment: you can use flutter data table to render table information in data rows and data columns and data cells

Comment: Hi I would like to implement it in flutter web, do you know some available packages?

Comment: how can i use porperties like overflow, maxlines in it??

Comment: What if there will be video or image link inside html?

Answer (score 14):

### I've just done the followings and it works fine.

1. Add **flutter_html** to your pubspec.yaml file.

> ```
> dependencies:
>   flutter:
>     sdk: flutter
>   flutter_html: ^0.8.2
> ```

2. Run the following command to update packages.

> `flutter pub get`

3. Import **flutter_html**

> `import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';`

4. Replace Text widget with Html widget.

> ```
>    child: 
>    // Text(
>    //   "Hello Programmer",
>    //   style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
>    // ),
>    Html(data:"<p>Hello <b>Flutter</b><p>"),
> ```

Comment: What if there will be video or image link inside html?

Answer (score 6):

Do not use `flutter_html_view` that reading at the [documentation](https://github.com/PonnamKarthik/FlutterHtmlView):

> **Supported Tags**
>
> - p
> - em
> - b
> - img
> - video
> - h1,
> - h2,
> - h3,
> - h4,
> - h5,
> - h6
> - Note
>
> *This plugin converts some of the html tags to flutter widgets This plugin does't support rendering full html code (there is no built in
>   support for web rendering in flutter)*

So it simply doesn't render well your html because it can't.

But you could find other pulugins, like `flutter_html`

https://github.com/Sub6Resources/flutter_html

and give them a try in order to see if they perform better.

[image]

**UPDATE**

In `pubspec.yaml` I've add

```
dependencies:
  flutter_html: ^0.8.2
```

and my `main.dart` is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  var html = "Follow<a class='sup'>pl</a> what was sent down to you from your Lord, and do not follow other guardians apart from Him. Little do <p class='h'>you remind yourselves</p><a class='f'><sup f=2437>1</a>.";


  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Html(
              data: html,
              ),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show me your code, i have checked but the pl not showing like yours.

Comment: @DeepakGehlot sure. I've updated my answer. I've just modified the standard Flutter Activity project to test it.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to your `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter_html:
```

**Currently Supported HTML Tags:**

*a, abbr, acronym, address, article, aside, b, bdi, bdo, big, blockquote, body, br, caption, cite, code, data, dd, del, dfn, div, dl, dt, em, figcaption, figure, footer, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hr, i, img, ins, kbd, li, main, mark, nav, noscript, ol, p, pre, q, rp, rt, ruby, s, samp, section, small, span, strike, strong, sub, sup, table, tbody, td, template, tfoot, th, thead, time, tr, tt, u, ul, var*

**Example Usage:**

```dart
Column(
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
   children: [
      new Html(
         data: "<b>Welcome</b>,
          defaultTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
       ),
     ],
)
```

Answer (score 3):

all the packages mentioned from other answers are no longer maintained ( at least when I write this answer), it will create conflict to other packages I use which has recent update, I end up using this package: [flutter_widget_from_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_widget_from_html) (ps: it is not mine)

Comment: I'm using the flutter_html: ^2.2.1, worked fine in android and iOS... this one give me some problems with the SDK version.

Answer (score 2):

Use [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) plugin

example:

```
new WebviewScaffold(
              url: new Uri.dataFromString('<html><body>hello world</body></html>', mimeType: 'text/html').toString()
```

**Webview inside custom Rectangle**

```
final flutterWebviewPlugin = new FlutterWebviewPlugin();

flutterWebviewPlugin.launch(url,
  fullScreen: false,
  rect: new Rect.fromLTWH(
    0.0,
    0.0,
    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    300.0,
  ),
);
```

Comment: WebView cannot be add to the widget tree, ain’t it. Or am I miss something?

Comment: Have you checked the example code ? https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart

Comment: its a Scaffold not a widget, if you want to insert into your existing page then you can make use of the webview in a rectangle flutterWebViewPlugin.launch(
                  selectedUrl,
                  rect: Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 300.0),
                  userAgent: kAndroidUserAgent,
                );

Comment: Yep, I had :-). That's the reason of my question ***Warning:** The webview is not integrated in the widget tree, it is a native view on top of the flutter view. you won't be able to use snackbars, dialogs ...* The example code use it as a page not in the widget tree.

Comment: create your own scaffold and render the webview inside a rectangle, then you can use snackbars, dialog, etc

Comment: Glad to know that, thanks. But I guess that that is beyond the OP question. Didn't you think that should be too much code to obtain what he's asking for?

Comment: unable to load this html using this plugin too, i have user WebviewScaffold just for testing and its not loading showing error "string contains invalid characters."

<html><body> Follow<a class='sup'><sup>pl</sup></a> what was sent down to you from your Lord, and do not follow other guardians apart from Him. Little do <span class='h'>you remind yourselves</span><a class='f'><sup f=2437>1</sup></a>. </body></html>

Comment: here is the working code https://gist.github.com/shyjuzz/d6fd5562f97b36b0e2eb957eff3c687a

Comment: https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/issues/772

Comment: I get `Contains invalid characters.`

Answer (score 2):

In the pubspec.yml add the following:

```
dependencies:
  flutter_html:
```

Then run:

```
flutter clean && flutter pub get
```

Finally, add the code like this:

```
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';
.
.
.
body: Center( Html(
      data: """
            <div>This is the start of a div
              <a class='sup'><sup>a sup</sup></a> 
              and after sub
              <b>Bold</b>
              <h1>This is a header with number 1557</h1> 
              A text and 
            <span class='h'>some stuff</div>
            """,
    ),)
```

[image: Screenshot from phone]

Until now, it works fine on both mobile and web.

Comment: What if there will be video or image link inside html?

Comment: I tried using images before and it worked fine. I didn't try videos but I think it would be fine too. Please, share your experience with us after trying it.

Answer (score 1):

might be a little late but i've made a project that accepts    and  tags

so you can do this

```
HTMLText('<b><i>SOME VERY IMPORTANT TEXT</i></b>');
```

and it'll translate your HTML into flutter based widgets and respect dark/light theme colors as well.

https://github.com/forumics/flutter-html-text

Answer (score 1):

To convert HTML to TextWidget, you can use the [html](https://pub.dev/packages/html) package. Here's an example:

First of add the dependency

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  html: ^0.15.0
  url_launcher: ^6.1.10
```

After that import the package and use the parse method to convert the HTML string to a Document object:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:html/parser.dart' show parse;
import 'package:html/dom.dart' as dom;
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class HtmlToRichTextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? htmlString;

  const HtmlToRichTextWidget({Key? key, this.htmlString = ''})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final document = html_parser.parse(htmlString);
    final inlineSpans = _parseNode(document.body!);

    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
          children: inlineSpans, style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
    );
  }

  List<InlineSpan> _parseNode(dom.Node node) {
    final inlineSpans = <InlineSpan>[];

    if (node.nodeType == dom.Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      final text = node.text;
      inlineSpans.add(TextSpan(text: text));
    } else if (node.nodeType == dom.Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      final element = node as dom.Element;

      switch (element.localName) {
        case "b":
        case 'strong':
          return _parseElements(
              element, const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold));
        case "i":
        case 'em':
          return _parseElements(
              element, const TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic));
        case "u":
          return _parseElements(
              element, const TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline));
        case "sub":
          inlineSpans.add(WidgetSpan(
            alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.bottom,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 10,
              child: Text(
                element.text,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ));
          break;
        case "sup":
          inlineSpans.add(WidgetSpan(
            alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.top,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 10,
              child: Text(
                element.text,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ));
          break;
        case "p":
          return _parseElements(element, const TextStyle());
        case "span":
          // print(element.className);
          return _parseElements(element, const TextStyle(color: Colors.red));

        case "a":
          final href = element.attributes['href'] ?? '';
          return _parseElements(
              element,
              const TextStyle(
                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline, color: Colors.blue),
              href);
        case 'br':
          inlineSpans.add(const TextSpan(text: "\n"));
          break;
        default:
          return _parseElements(element, const TextStyle());
      }
    }

    return inlineSpans;
  }

  List<InlineSpan> _parseElements(dom.Element element, TextStyle style,
      [String? href]) {
    final spans = <InlineSpan>[];

    for (final node in element.nodes) {
      final childTextSpans = _parseNode(node);

      for (final childTextSpan in childTextSpans) {
        var launch = TapGestureRecognizer()
          ..onTap = () => launchUrl(Uri.tryParse(href ?? "")!);
        if (childTextSpan is TextSpan) {
          spans.add(
            TextSpan(
              text: childTextSpan.text,
              style: style.merge(childTextSpan.style),
              recognizer: href != null ? launch : null,
            ),
          );
        } else {
          spans.add(childTextSpan);
          print(childTextSpan.toString());
        }
      }
    }
    return spans;
  }
}
```

In the updated version, we added support for the tag to the switch statement in the _parseNode method. We also updated the _parseElements method to accept an optional href parameter, which we use to create a TapGestureRecognizer and add to the TextSpan when a tag is encountered.

You'll need to `import package:flutter/gestures.dart` and `package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart` from [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package to use the TapGestureRecognizer and launch function.

Comment: Thank you for this light and efficient solution :-)

Answer (score -1):

if you have list of object and need to groupBy you can use following link:
[groupBy_in_flutter](https://fluttertutorial.in/groupby-in-flutter/)