# Display text html in TextField

Tags: html, flutter, dart, textfield

I want to display html text in TextField in Flutter
[image]
How can I do that? Please help me

I don't know how can do it.

Comment: I don't know much about flutter, but you might be able to use [flutter_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html). Also, look through the answers to the following question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53815485/how-to-show-html-string-in-text-widget-flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53815485/how-to-show-html-string-in-text-widget-flutter). This should help you.

Comment: @OfficerErikK This is TextField not Text. I want html is showed on TextField.

Answer (score -1):

You can check the html packages in pub.dev. If you can't find the package you want, you should write the replaceAll method yourself one by one.